# A quick c++ array initialization question using non const variable

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am very new to C++ and I am wondering if I can do the following,

```
int a =5;
int b[a];
```

If so, what would happen if value of a changed? and any drawback using this.

If not,why it that?

thanks!

I tried the same code on an online c++ compiler and it does work. but i just dont know if this is a standard practice or not. if not, what would be the standard practices of refering a dynamic value to initialize an array?

Comment: It's not standard C++, unless `a` is const. *Some* compilers may allow it anyway, as an extension. `std::vector` allows you to use a runtime size.

Comment: No, that's not legal c++.

Comment: `int a{5}; std::vector<int> b(a);` is allowed [introduction to vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do that. Array bounds in C++ must be constants. This is legal

```
const int a = 5; // a is a constant
int b[a];
```

Some compilers do allow your code, but it is an extension to the C++ language called a *variable length array* or VLA.

But even on the compilers that do allow it, nothing happens to `b` if you change `a`, it will still have the same size as when it was created.

You can avoid all these issues by using a vector, like this `std::vector<int> b(a);` That is the correct way to do what you are asking for. You need to `#include <vector>` for the `std::vector` class.